# Javascript: Does not change the div innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I really cannot understand why this does not work. I've tried couple of tricks but I just don't get it.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
alert('Hey');
    var vText = document.getElementById("results");
        vText.innerHTML = 'Changed';
        alert(vText.innerHTML);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="results">
hey there
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please post your HTML code, in best case provide an jsfiddle (jsfiddle.net) which makes it easier for us to help you

Comment: @rami Working on it, right now

Comment: @Hoque I've written this basically in textEdit and trying to view it on Safari

Comment: where did you keep that script? In a fuction?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sK7GU/ check this fiddle . the snippet you shown us , have no issues..Everybody here guessing this can be the problem, unless showing your HTML file it's quiet hard to fix...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is working as you can see here:

http://jsfiddle.net/gHbss/

It's important that you put the JavaScript after your HTML div container.

Answer (score 4):

The problem that you're facing is that the browser runs the JavaScript as it's encountered when rendering/processing the page. At this point it will `alert()` your message, but the relevant element, the `#results` `div` isn't present in the DOM, so nothing can be changed.

To address this, you can either place the `script` at the end of the page, just before the closing `</body>` tag, or run the code in the `onload` event of the `body` or `window`.

Answer (score 1):

The script has to be placed after the div#results or executed onload, otherwise the element is still unknown when you try to access it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call this script in onload event
i.e

```
 window.onload=function(){
//your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function onloadCall()
{
    alert('Hey');
    var vText = document.getElementById("results");                                                 
    vText.innerHTML = 'Changed';
    alert(vText.innerHTML);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="onloadCall()">
    <div id="results">
    hey there
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope the above snippet shows you the fix