# Using innerHTML has no effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use javascript to dynamically change the header to my website and thus the header was not changing. My html, for simplicity, looks like

```
&ltdiv class="container"&gt
  &lth1 id="name"&gtNic&lt/h1&g
  &ltp id="email"&gt&lt/p&gt
  &lthr&gt
&lt/div&gt

&ltscript src="js/something.js"&gt&lt/script&gt
```

My javascript lives in a file called something.js and looks like

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    console.log('I got run');
    $('#name').innerHTML = "YO";
    $('#email').innerHTML = "why hello";
})
```

For some reason I see the log in the console but the html never changes. Why is the header not getting changed?

I did try looking at the stack overflow question 
[Javascript: Does not change the div innerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10157983/javascript-does-not-change-the-div-innerhtml)
and here [Setting innerHTML: Why won't it update the DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8196240/setting-innerhtml-why-wont-it-update-the-dom) and many others however none of them address my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery doesn't have `innerHTML` property to set html instead it has method.

Use **[`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)** if your content is only plain text

Like this

```
 $('#name').text("YO");
```

If it has html content then use **[`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)**

Like this

```
 $('#name').html("<p>YO</p>");
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/L378hLra/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

In jQuery you use .html("text") instead of .innerHTML

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    console.log('I got run');
    $('#name').html("YO");
    $('#email').html("why hello");
})
```